# Apache & mod_wsgi settings for Django Python Project

Tags: python, django, apache, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup my django-python project on Google Compute Engine Debian8 VM. I made few config changes in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf & /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` files
Then tried to restart the server. And I got following Errors. Uninstalling & reinstalling the apache2 too is not fixing this error. Any suggestions to fix this issue ?

Command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Command:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l
```

Error:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2016-08-31 05:08:43 UTC; 3min 37s ago
  Process: 3539 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3521 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3546 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Starting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
.
Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the error ? It's clearly stated why it fails:

> Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file: **No such file or directory**

do you have `libapache2-mod-wsgi` or `libapache2-mod-wsgi-python3` installed? if you have access to shell you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
# or for python 3
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran the Command to see the process running on port 80:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

Output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24482/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      24482/nginx -g daem
```

Running the next two commands then fixed the issue:

```
sudo kill -9 24482
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it can be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: If nginx was managed as a service, you may find it starts back up again and nginx and Apache will fight to get port 80 each time the host is restarted. You should ensure nginx isn't set up to be automatically started as a service.

Comment: No idea. Depends on what supervisor system your Linux variant is using.